# Equivalent of net use (to list computer's connections) in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, net-use

According to windows help NET USE, when used without options, lists the computer's connections.

I'd like to find a way in powershell to get a list of the Remote entries in net use's output.

I know that as an extreme measure I can parse the result of the "net use" command itself, but I'd rather not rely on the text output of that command.

Can anybody help me out?
thank you

Michele

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
OK                     \\SERVER02\example          Microsoft Windows Network  
OK                     \\SERVER02\prova            Microsoft Windows Network  
Disconnected           \\SERVER03\test             Microsoft Windows Network  
OK                     \\SERVER02\remoteshare      Microsoft Windows Network  
Disconnected           \\SERVER03\remoteshare
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the mapped logical drive you can use WMI class [Win32_MappedLogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_MappedLogicalDisk
```

Here is another way with [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  :

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4"

DeviceID     : V:
DriveType    : 4
ProviderName : \\jpbdellf1\c$
FreeSpace    :
Size         :
VolumeName   :
```

---

Edited

You are right, you can get what you need with [Win32_NetworkConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
PS > Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkConnection

LocalName                     RemoteName                    ConnectionState               Status
---------                     ----------                    ---------------               ------
                              \\jpbasusf1\temp              Connected                     OK
```

On Seven or W2K8 be careful to call this with the same user that run the NET USE because it's a session information.

Comment: I Edit my answer, I think that this time it's better.